# How to unhide filtered messages in Chrome developer Tools 60

Tags: google-chrome, filter, hidden, console.log, developer-tools

In the developer view in Chrome, under the console tab, it's showing this message

> 9 items hidden by filters

I clicked on parameters icon and i have (screnshot) :

[image]

I dont find how to unhide this items ...

Answer (score 12):

If you right-click on the surface of the console, you can go to filter, then unhide all. A few items still seem to be hidden for me though[image]

**Update (Oct '18):**

It looks like it got moved to a textbox at the top of the console, named "Filter" and a dropbox box next to it for the levels.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dan,

I saw also an another way to unhide all,
On my screenshot, you have to click on "Hide All", and choose "default".

It was so obvious !!

Comment: The above comment should be marked as the solution! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Cannot find it on Version 69.0.3497.100

Comment: It looks like it got moved to a textbox at the top of the console, named "Filter" and a dropbox box next to it for the levels.

Answer (score 6):

You can also press f1 while in the developer console and then select the "restore to default" button in the bottom right.

Comment: Great answer, @to240 ! That's what solved the unwanted filtering of messages for me.